# Difference between Axon Framework and Axon server

Tags: axon, axon-framework

what is the difference between **Axon Framework** and **Axon Server**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Axon Server](https://developer.axoniq.io/axon-server) is a zero-configuration **message router** and an **event store**. It serves two purposes

- it routes messages (commands, queries, and events) between distributed components (microservices) in a location transparent way.
- it stores events allowing distributed (often event sourced) applications to have a single source of truth.

[Axon Framework](https://developer.axoniq.io/axon-framework) is an open-source Java framework for building event-driven applications (monolith, modulith or microservices). It makes it easy for developers to implement architectural principles, such as **Domain-Driven Design** (DDD), **Command-Query Responsibility Separation** (CQRS), and **Event Sourcing** (ES)

You could use Axon Framework without Axon Server if you don't have a distributed architecture or when you want to build the communication between components yourself.

You could theoretically use Axon Server without Axon Framework but you'd have to communicate with it through a relatively low-level API.

From everything said above, it should be clear that Axon Framework and Axon Server are designed to complement each other and be used together (at least in a mission-critical application).